# tailwind doesn't change the div background while using responsive breaking points

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, tailwind-css

i have the following problem, i'm trying to change the background of my div when it reach to 412px screen resolution, the problem is that even than i'm using max-[412px] as a breaking point to make the change, the div never change it background, here is the code:

```
<div className="  overflow-auto bg-opacity-50 bg-[url('../images/andrea-inicio.jpg')]  h-[calc(75vh+35px)]  bg-[length:100%_100%] max-[412px]:bg-blue ">
```

thanks in advance!

i'm trying to change the background of the div, if the screen resolution reach to 412px, change to the background image if it is less than 412px change it to the blue background